# SQL rounding to 7 places, even though its set as decimal(18,4))

Tags: sql-server-2005, rounding

```
select (cast(datediff(minute,'1900-01-01 07:03:00.000' ,'1900-01-01 10:35:00.000')

as decimal(18,4))/60)
```

Even though the decimal places are set to 4, it returns
3.5333333
instead of 
3.5333

Please help me return 3.5333 (4 decimal places)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/4119/0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the /60 in the cast and change it to 60.0 to have a decimals.

```
select (cast(datediff(minute,'1900-01-01 07:03:00.000' ,'1900-01-01 10:35:00.000')/60.0

as decimal(18,4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do your division before casting:

```
select 
   cast(datediff(minute, '1900-01-01 07:03:00.000', '1900-01-01 10:35:00.000') / 60.0 
        as decimal(18,4))
```

Then you get:

```
3.5333
```

Casting to `decimal(18,4)` and *then* doing a division by 60 sort of "invalidates" your formatting - SQL Server will show all the numeric precision of that division by 60 again...